# Inheritance Issue in C# : CS7036

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

For some reason I'm getting an error in the constructor method "ModifiedExercise"
CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter `name` of `Exercise.Exercise(string,int,int,string,string[],Dictionary<string,bool>)`
I added the Parent and child classes `Exercise` and `ModifiedExercise`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Trainer_App
{
    internal class ModifiedExercise : Exercise 
    {
        private Exercise regular_exercise;
        public ModifiedExercise(Exercise regular_exercise,
                                string name,
                                int min_num_balls,
                                int participants_num,
                                string court_type,
                                string[] accessories,
                                Dictionary<string, bool> exerciseTypes)
        {
            this.regular_exercise = regular_exercise;
            this.id = Exercise.id_counter;
            Exercise.id_counter++;
            this.name = name;
            this.min_num_balls = min_num_balls;
            this.participants_num = participants_num;
            this.court_type = court_type;
            this.accessories = accessories;
            this.exerciseTypes = exerciseTypes;

        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Trainer_App
{
    internal class Exercise
    {
        protected static int id_counter = 0;
        protected int id;
        protected string name;
        protected int min_num_balls;
        protected int participants_num;
        protected string court_type;
        protected string[] accessories;
        protected static int exerciseCounter = 0;
        protected Dictionary<string, bool> exerciseTypes = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

        public Exercise(string name,int min_num_balls, int participants_num,string court_type, string[]accessories,Dictionary<string,bool> exerciseTypes)
        {
            this.id = id_counter;
            id_counter++;
            this.name = name;
            this.min_num_balls = min_num_balls;
            this.participants_num = participants_num;
            this.court_type = court_type;
            this.accessories = accessories;
            this.exerciseTypes = exerciseTypes;
        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default constructors effectively call `: base()` on their base type

You have two options here:

1. Add a `protected Exercise(){}` parameterless constructor to the base type
2. Add an explicit `: base(...)` explicitly specifying which value to pass in which position to the base constructor

Note : 2 is the usual approach, to reduce duplication. This also allows the fields to remain `private`.

Comment: Used Method 2, worked perfectly and also made sense so I will be using this method again, if needed, though the fields are still protected(it gave me a "protection level" error)

Comment: @GaelPinto remember that you don't need to assign the fields in the derived constructor, if the base constructor has already done it